# Oracle: Insert records in a table from the join result of other tables avoiding duplication of records

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am new to Oracle SQL and PL/SQL. 
I have been tasked to get records from 3 tables. mccm_ops_monitoring_1_day, which contains current day's data, mccm_ops_monitoring_7_days which contains data from last 7 days. Based on joins of these tables along with a static table alarm_control_table, I need to find the difference between values of current day and last 7 days avg. The result should be grouped from mccm_ops_monitoring_1_day at 15 min. intervals. I have created the query and getting the desired result.
The trouble is, I have to put these results in another table which gets updated every 15 minutes by running the query. I tried to do it using a procedure and scheduled a job but that caused duplication of records for as many times as the job ran. Therefore, I had to drop the procedure. I tried using materialized view but it was not getting refreshed by itself.

The query is as follows. Please help me find a solution.

```
SELECT
    to_timestamp((TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-RR')|| ' '|| TO_CHAR(m.contact_date,'HH:MI:SS AM')), 'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS AM') AS contact_date,
    m.interactivechannelname,
    m.interactionpointname,
    nvl(m.channel_type,'UNKNOWN')channel_type,
    m.cbu,
    m.segment,
    m.visits todays_visits,
    nvl(w.visits,0) last_7_days_visits,
    m.visits - nvl(w.visits,0) today_vs_7days_visits_diff,
    m.accepts todays_accepts,
    nvl(w.accepts,0) last_7_days_accepts,
    m.accepts - nvl(w.accepts,0) today_vs_7days_accepts,
    CASE
            WHEN ( m.visits - w.visits ) / 100 > c.visit_threshold OR ( w.visits - m.visits ) / 100 > c.visit_threshold THEN 'YES'
            WHEN ( m.accepts - w.accepts ) / 100 > c.accept_threshold OR ( w.accepts - m.accepts ) / 100 > c.accept_threshold THEN 'YES'
        END
    AS alert_msg,
    CASE
            WHEN ( m.visits - w.visits ) / 100 > c.visit_threshold OR ( w.visits - m.visits ) / 100 > c.visit_threshold THEN c.alarm_text
            WHEN ( m.accepts - w.accepts ) / 100 > c.accept_threshold OR ( w.accepts - m.accepts ) / 100 > c.accept_threshold THEN c.alarm_text
        END
    AS alarm_text
FROM
    mccm_ops_monitoring_1_days m
    LEFT JOIN mccm_ops_monitoring_7_days w ON TO_CHAR(m.contact_date,'HH24:MI:SS AM') = TO_CHAR(w.contact_date,'HH24:MI:SS AM')
                                              AND m.interactivechannelname = w.interactivechannelname
                                              AND m.interactionpointname = w.interactionpointname
                                              AND nvl(m.channel_type,'UNKNOWN') = nvl(w.channel_type,'UNKNOWN')
                                              AND m.cbu = w.cbu
                                              AND m.segment = w.segment
    LEFT JOIN alarm_control_table c ON m.interactivechannelname = c.interactivechannelname
                                 AND m.interactionpointname = c.interactionpointname
                                 AND nvl(m.channel_type,'UNKNOWN') = nvl(c.channel_type,'UNKNOWN')
                                 AND m.cbu = c.cbu
                                 AND m.segment = c.segment;
```

Comment: use procedure and job to repopulate the table which gets updated every 15 minutes by inserting new records and updating old records in that table using DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement allows you can truncate and load the data in your procedure. It should resolve the duplicate issue.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I tries to add truncate, but in that case the table will not have previous day data since that will get truncated the next day once the job runs.

Comment: @Rajmat483 I suggested to truncate the table getting inserted at every 15 minutes. Do you need to have all the data getting inserted in 15 minutes interval?

Comment: That is, assuming you insert 1 million, in one hour it'll be 4 million. Do you need all the 4 versions in the table? In that case the table will grow unreasonably large as time goes.